# Bootstrap - Issue with Multiple Modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

i am trying to make a bootstrap website, and im having an issue with modals.

I can make the first one fine, but when i go to make the second one it just wont open?

the only linking tag i can see in the code is:

```
 div class="modal fade" id="project-modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="project-modal-label" aria-hidden="true" >
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
```

And this is what i have on the image i want to link:

```
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#project-modal1">
     <img src="img/port1.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

is there abything im missing? as i said, one works fine, but when i add a second and change the "id" it wont load?

Comment: you need to open it by calling javascript

Answer (score 0):

I have an internal site at work using bootstrap modals and on my `a` elements I have the `href` set as `href="#project-modal1"` and don't event have a `data-target` attribute and it works great.

Comment: How would you apply that to multiple? 

I.e what element in the actual modal display code could you relate that to?

Comment: @CarlM I have multiple modals with different id's, and each link has the `href` reflect the id of the modal. Does that make sense? Like you have `id="project-modal1"` and I'm guessing another `id="project-modal2"`, so the `href` for one `a` would be `href="#project-modal1"` and the other `a` would have `href="#project-modal2"`

Comment: Hmm, i tried that. But it opens both models with the first image? but the second still dosent load anything?

Comment: @CarlM Hmm, can you post more of your markup here? The entire modal markup might help.